# How do I get web browser to start when clicking links in Outlook?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook, internet-explorer

I've got a problem with Outlook 2010 on an XP box.  Web links inside e-mails are highlighted and underlined just like normal, but when I click on them, nothing happens.  Links fire off the browser fine from other applications.  Looks like it's just Outlook that's affected.  Googled this some and found a couple suggestions already, but none of them worked, so I might have an uncommon problem here...  :-(

Comment: Is it possible that your security settings are too high?

Comment: @variant Make that an answer instead of a comment please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you check your security settings. They might be set too high to permit opening URLs from emails.

Comment: That did it this time.  I've done full browser resets already with no change.  Apparently the full browser reset does not include security level...

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted out.